# is it secure to put a react-firebase application on github?

Tags: auth0

I'm looking at this doc from auth0 re a react+firebase application and am not sure, if you include the client_id on github, does that cause any security issue? thanks.

(excerpt from configure Auto0Lock)

```
var App = React.createClass({
  // ...
  componentWillMount: function() {
      this.lock = new Auth0Lock('YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_NAMESPACE');
  },
  // ...
});
```

source: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/firebase

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/api/v2 - Under their "Security considerations" section they actually suggest that you do not: 1) Dynamically generate tokens because it can expose your API Secret, 2) allow other users to see your API Token or Secret.  However,only having access to the Client ID would still not allow another person to generate tokens for your application(s) without knowing the API secret.

Comment: You could store your config keys / ids in a config.js file and add that to the gitignore that way no one will have access to your keys but it will still run locally

Comment: @erichardson30 do you have any github samples for how to use a config.js file in this way? I am unsure what terms to google for examples. thanks.

Comment: when I try to research like "secure api key client js" then the resulting articles seem to indicate that this is not possible. does it mean that if I need to make any call using an api key, then I must use a server side call in order to do this securely?

Comment: @cchung https://github.com/erichardson30/norrisBot/blob/master/bin/bot.js and config.js is not in the github because it has the keys and it just locally in my project. You can also set environment variables and get those through process.env.ENV_VAR_NAME